# How to get Symfony repository inside a class

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, repository

I build validation system with Respect/Validation and I have validation rule for country name:

```
class CountryName extends AllOf
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            new StringType(),
            new NotEmpty(),
            new Alpha(),
            new Length(1, 100),
            new CountryNameUnique()
        );
    }
}
```

Inside CountryNameUnique I have to check name in database. Structure of class is simple:

```
class CountryNameUnique extends AbstractRule
{
    public function validate($input)
    {
        // validation here

        return false;
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to get repository inside of CountryNameUnique. My services.yml

> ```
> App\Domain\Country\Infrastructure\Repository\CountryRepository:
>     public: true
>     class: App\Domain\Country\Infrastructure\Repository\CountryRepository
>     factory: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", getRepository]
>     arguments: [App\Domain\Country\Entity\Country]
> ```

I would very appreciate if somebody give me a right direction how to solve my problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to make your CountryName a service.

Comment: You need to make CountryNameUnique class as a service and instead of creating the object by your own in CountryName constructor, get the object from service manager

Comment: Thank you for reply. @RahulSingh I'm newbie with Symfony. Could you give me some example how to do that? How can I get the object from service manager?

Comment: I made some tests. Looks like a have to pass container from controller through all my generic php classes made for validation.

Answer (score 0):

As for all services `autowire` is enabled by default, you can inject the repository service by getting the repository in constructor method.

```
class CountryNameUnique
{
    private $countryRepository;

    public function __construct(CountryRepository $countryRepository)
    {
        $this->countryRepository = $countryRepository;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: right, but I get error in line new CountryNameUnique() that I have to pass argument.